# tax exempt for Taxcloud in Odoo 10 enterprise

Tags: enterprise, odoo-10

In Odoo 10 Enterprise how would we exempt some customers without having to provide an exemption certificate?  We may have many government customers who don't pay sales tax (cities, counties, states, military bases, etc.).
Also do we have Tax Exempt Certificate option for taxcloud in Odoo 10 enterprise?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

**Quick Answer:** Yes, the Odoo TaxCloud implementation has automated exemption certificates on-board, but exempt purchasers will have to fill out the form **once** (17 fields, shouldn't take more than 2 minutes, once).

**Developer Answer:**
Please review our excellent [developer-oriented exemption certificates implementation guide](https://dev.taxcloud.com/guides/exemption-certificates)

**Detailed Answer:** This is less an Odoo question, and more a tax law question.

[Notice: This post should not be considered as *"tax advice"*. You should direct questions of this nature to a licensed CPA or tax attorney.]

1. Exempt entities are **required** to provide retailers with
   documentation (frequently *exemption certificates*) to substantiate
   their claim for tax exempt treatment.
2. Retailers are **required** to collect applicable sales tax on all
   sales, unless the purchaser qualifies as an exempt entity.

As a business decision, and as a convenience to exempt purchases, *some* retailers will allow a sale to proceed without obtaining an exemption certificate, but only because many states allow retailers up to 90 days after completing a sales to obtain the necessary documentation.

However, during audit **the retailer will be held liable** for all uncollected sales tax (including delinquent penalties, fines, and accrued interest) unless they provide the auditor with evidence of purchasers' exempt entity status (obtained within 90 days of sale).